# Trying to write a java code to authenticate Graph API

Tags: java, authentication, azure

I'm trying to write a java code to authenticate the graph API by the Azure Access Control Service (ACS) using OAuth 2.0.

Based on what I've read, They are four steps to this

1. Generate an assertion which includes the Service Principal’s X.509 Certificate (alternatively, a symmetric key can also be used).
2. Present the assertion to the Azure ACS Security Token Service (STS).
3. ACS accepts the assertion and authenticates the Service Principal, returning a minted OAuth access token (i.e. JWT token).
4. Subsequent API call submissions include the access token.

Can anyone tell me, where do I begin this from? For example, where can I find the java api, how do I generate a symmetric key or an assertion with X.509 cert. I want to create an java app which will create users in the office 365 and authenticating is the initial step. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to start from here:

[How to Authenticate Web Users with Windows Azure Access Control Service Using Eclipse](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/access-control/) - This  example uses Windows Live ID for the identity provider, a similar technique could be used for other identity providers as applicable.

Once you have your Java based code is authenticating users successfully you can go ahead and implement further to connect with other providers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that will help. I kind of got stuck in the start where I"m trying to get a ACS Plugin for eclipse. I'm on a MAC and using juno ecipse. Is there a way I can get the plugin in installed, if not is there a work around?

I've posted the error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588463/difficulty-in-installing-windows-azure-access-control-services-filter-plugin-for

Comment: You may need to run a Windows virtual machine on Mac to get this working as most of the code is designed/tested with Azure SDK 1.8.