# Difficulty in Installing Windows Azure Access Control Services filter plugin for java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, azure

I'm trying to install the ACS plugin using this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx

But, I'm getting this error.

Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  com.microsoftopentechnologies.acsfilter.feature.feature.group [0.2.0.201211010928] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Any idea what needs to be done?

I've Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Windows or non-Windwows OS? As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx) this plugin requires Windows Azure SDK 1.8 in the machine and without it you will hit error:

```
This plugin requires Windows Azure SDK 1.8. This can be downloaded using the Web Platform Installer (WebPI) at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252838. However, if you don’t have it installed, when you create your first Windows Azure deployment project, the plugin will automatically install Windows Azure SDK 1.8.
```

You can get an test Windows machine to give a try first and then learn how you can port the code to other machine. Not a clean way to achieve what you want but at least you have some option.